# How can I do a multiple regression with data collected annually over 5 years?

Tags: regression

I'm trying to find out how which of six governance indicators has the most significance on FDI inflows into a region of 16 countries. I have 3 control variables, and the data has been collected annually over 5 years. I think a multiple regression would be appropriate and I'm using SPSS, but I'm unsure of how to deal with time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have such a small number of observations (80 assuming same number of observations for all countries?) I think this is testing the limits of what you can do with regression analysis. The kind of data you describe is normally analysed using panel data estimators (e.g. fixed effects, random effects) which I believe are referred to as "mixed models" on SPSS. But even with this kind of analysis, with that number of observations it's not really feasible and you're unlikely to find meaningful results.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative at all? Thank you

Comment: Also, the 6 independent variables are indicators with a range of -2.5 to 2.5. How will this affect the results as opposed to say, a range of 0 to 5?